# How to recreate samba secrets.tdb file

Tags: samba, centos6

While trying to setup samba on an NFS server I deleted (don't ask) the `/var/lib/samba/` contents and now when I try to start samba, this messages appears :

```
[2012/07/06 08:19:07.528973,  0] passdb/secrets.c:73(secrets_init)
  Failed to open /var/lib/samba/private/secrets.tdb
[2012/07/06 08:19:07.689735,  0] passdb/secrets.c:73(secrets_init)
  Failed to open /var/lib/samba/private/secrets.tdb
[2012/07/06 08:19:07.690078,  0] smbd/server.c:1240(main)
  ERROR: smbd can not open secrets.tdb
```

So how do I recreate the `secrets.tdb` file and the rest of the needed files if any ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [smbpasswd](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbpasswd.8.html) which will create the file if it doesn't exist when you add a new user

```
ls -l /var/lib/samba/private/secrets.tdb
ls: cannot access /var/lib/samba/private/secrets.tdb: No such file or directory

smbbpasswd iain
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:

ls -l /var/lib/samba/private/secrets.tdb
-rw-------. 1 root root 45056 Jul  6 07:54 /var/lib/samba/private/secrets.tdb
```

Comment: This only works is the directory /var/lib/samba/private exists. If it doesn't just make it via mkdir then execute the smbpasswd -a user