# Samba & LDAP: did not correctly init (error was NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY)

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, samba

I am trying to configure Samba to authenticate with a new ldap domain. In the logs I am seeing the following error:

pdb backend ldapsam:ldaps: did not correctly init (error was NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY).

I have enabled verbose logging to try to get more information.

What does (error was NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY) mean? Is it an issue on the Samba server or the Ldap server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message while upgrading an old samba server (stretch to buster, to bullseye). I could solve it by recreating the secrets.tdb (see [How to recreate samba secrets.tdb file](https://serverfault.com/questions/405301/how-to-recreate-samba-secrets-tdb-file)) and by changing the line in /etc/samba/smb.conf where the `ldap admin dn` is specified. The value for this was contained in quotes. By removing the quotes I could start the samba server.